# url rewrite : explorer can't find the page but the script gets executed ?

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

this is my original URL , this is a activation link that I'll send to the users email to active their accounts

```
www.m.com/activation.php?active=c663f71e95e242416488e0de7861db8f
```

I'm trying to rewrite it to be like

```
www.m.com/activation/c663f71e95e242416488e0de7861db8f/
```

this is my htaccess code :

```
^activation/([a0-z9]*)/$ activation.php?active=$1
```

here is my activation.php code
it will active the user and then redirect the user to his/her profile

```
<?php

$active_code = isset($_GET['active'])? $_GET['active'] : exit ;
$user = user::find_unactive_user($active_code);
if($user){
$user->active();
header('location:profile.php');
}else echo 'cant find user';

?>
```

now the weird thing is when i click on the activation link explorer redirects me to the 404 error page so apparently it cant find the page with given url 
but user status will be changed to active and that means script has been executed !

what I'm doing wrong ?

here is my htaccess  page just in case

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
Options Indexes
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Please enter your ID and password"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user 
order deny,allow

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.m.com/404.php

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite numeric URLs
RewriteRule ^project-([0-9]*)-.*\.html$ project.php?project=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^project-([0-9]*)\.html$ project.php?project=$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^activation/([a0-z9]*)/$ activation.php?active=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What is this: `[a0-z9]`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have error in url:

```
^activation/([a0-z9]*)/$ activation.php?active=$1
//should be
^activation/([a-z0-9]*)/$ activation.php?active=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to correct: first the Regexp is not valid (see Sudhir), and you forgot QSA to keep things that were appended as GET, and maybe NC flag (= not case sensitive):

```
RewriteRule ^activation/([a-z0-9]*)/$ activation.php?active=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```